# How to run a scala project at high speed in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: scala

How to run a scala project at high speed in Intellij IDEA?
I wrote a scala project that uses Figaro libraries, but when I run it in Intellij IDEA, the execution speed is slow and gives a "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error. I want to know how this problem can be solved?

Comment: Increase Java heap space?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into how are you allocating memory. If you have too many references to objects (specially larger ones) you wil run into this problem.

As a quick fix you can add `-Xmx` to the run configuration arguments to set the heap size to the max possible given the OS. In windows I believe it's 2GB while the java default is much smaller.

Anyways if you don't follow the first advice, you will run into this problem again.